# Time Series Forecasting: weekly vs daily predictions

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science, arima

I have some daily time series data. I am trying to predict the next 3 days from the historical daily set of data.

The historical data shows a definite trend based upon the day-of-week such as Monday, Tuesday, etc Monday and Tuesdays are high, Wednesday typically highest and then decreasing over the remaining part of the week.

If i group the data monthly or weekly, i can definitely see a trend over time going up that appears to be additive.

My goal is to predict the next 3 days only. My intuition is telling me to take one approach and I am hoping for some feedback on pros/cons versus other approaches.

My intuition tells me it might be better to group the data by week or month and then predict the next week or month. Suppose I predict the next week total by loading historical weekly data into ARIMA, train, test and predict the next week. Within a week, each Day-of-week typically contributes x percent to that weekly total. So, if Wednesday historically has on average contributed 50% of the weekly volume, and for the next week I am predicted 1000, then I would predict Wednesday to be 500. Is this a common approach?

Alternatively, I could load the historical daily values into ARIMA, train, test and let ARIMA predict the next 3 days. The big difference here is the whole "predict weekly" versus "predict daily".

In the time series forecasting space, is this a common debate and if so, perhaps someone can suggest some key words i can google to educate myself on pros/cons?

Also, perhaps there is a suggested algorithm to use when day of week is a factor?

Answer (score 4):

This is a standard daily time series problem where there is a day-of-week seasonality. If you are using R, you could make the time series a `ts` object with `frequency = 7` and then use `auto.arima()` from the forecast package to forecast it. Any other seasonal forecasting method is also potentially applicable.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I am using Python.  I have ran auto_arima and the orders can back as a SARIMAX(1, 0, 2)x(2, 1, 2, 7).  I have tested and trained the model and the resulting prediction has a RMSE Error: 7.053940399 where the average value of in the dataset is 28.3.  My gut says that is kinda high error.  Thoughts?